# C# WinForm - Italic in Date using DateTime Now and Color Of Label

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I make my DateTime Font to Italic and the color of the label to red.

Here's my code

```
// Date
String date = FontStyle.Italic( DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString() );

 if (lbl_remaining.Text == "0")
 {
            lbl_remaining.Text = FontColor.Red;
 }
```

These codes are error on my part. I don't know how can I make my date to Italic and label to color red.

Thank you in advance

Comment: That's one of the weirdest code snippet I ever saw in my life ...

Comment: If you click on the label in the designer, in the properties window you have a lot of settings you can change such as the font and color.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the label color :

```
lbl_remaining.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

For displaying the label in italic :

```
lbl_remaining.Font = new Font(lbl_remaining.Font.Name, 12, FontStyle.Italic);
```

Answer (score 2):

How something is displayed is totally different of what is shown.
So setting the text has nothing to do with font, color etc.

```
lbl_remaining.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();

lbl_remaining.Font = new Font("Arial", 24,FontStyle.Italic);
lbl_remaining.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```